# How to prevent stack (haskell) from running hpack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

My local machine and CI have different versions of `stack` (and `hpack`). Due to this reason there are minor differences in the `cabal` files auto-generated on my local machine vs the CI machine (mostly whitespace).

Due to `hpack` being run again in CI (even though the generated `cabal` files are checked into the repo), the `cabal` files change and end-up triggering a re-build in the CI.

Is there any way to invoke `stack install` or `stack build` in a way that they DONT run `hpack` again (and use the given `cabal` file)?

Comment: I don't think `stack` supports this directly. I can imagine two workarounds: 1. Delete any `package.yaml` files, so `stack` has to use the existing `*.cabal` files. 2. Try passing a fake `hpack` executable to the `--with-hpack` option, e.g. `--with-hpack /usr/bin/true`.